# In Python, how can I convert an integer between 0 and 255 to a single unsigned byte?

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer, unsigned-char

My laptop runs a Python program that reads a joystick to send a speed command to an Arduino that in turn controls the motor on a toy car. To do that the program converts an integer with values between 0 and 255 to a single unsigned byte that it sends over a serial connection to the Arduino.

This code works to do that:

```
           if event.axis == axis:
                speed = int((event.value + 1.0) / 2.0 * 255.0)
                speedCommand = bytearray(b'\x00')
                speedCommand[0] = speed
                speedCommand = bytes(speedCommand)
                ser.write(speedCommand)
                print(speed, speedCommand)
```

While that code works, it's not very elegant. I would like to find a one-line instruction that does the same thing as the three lines that start with "speedCommand". I tried this, for example:

```
            speedCommand = chr(speed).encode()
```

But it only works for 0 to 127. Any number above 127 encodes to two bytes[, as the character is seen as a signed byte with values above 127 being negative].

EDITED TO ADD: My assumption that "the character is seen as a signed byte with values above 127 being negative" may not be correct.

Comment: " as the character is seen as a signed byte with values above 127 being negative." I don't think that's what's going on, in any case, I've provided an answer

Comment: FYI `speed = chr(speed).encode('latin1')` would fix your encoding problem.  The encoding defaults to `utf8` otherwise

Comment: Mark Tolonen, that `chr(speed).encode('latin1')` solution does indeed work in my program. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need:

```
speed_command = bytes([speed])
```

The `bytes` constructor accepts an iterable of `int` objects, so just put it in a list when you pass it to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pack` method from the `struct` built-in module. It takes as first argument a format, and as next arguments a value (or multiple values) to pack into this format. For an `unsigned char`, the required format is `B`. The module supports many other formats, which might be useful for sending other data to your Arduino. See [the `struct` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for more information, including [a list of format characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).

```
>>> import struct
>>> speed = 255
>>> struct.pack('B', speed)
b'\xff'
```

Comment: That `struct` module is a good one to know about in sending data to the Arduino. I can use it in a couple of other places in my program. Thanks.